# In Node js - Emit event for particular user in Socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

Currently I have facing issue that I got response to all users.
I want to just notify for Selected user in single chat module.

like below i want to sent notification to this "userid" only

Client side file code has below

```
var forwardString = 

{
    "userid": actual_receiverID,
    "id": msgId
};

socket.emit('insertReceiverIdInMessageForwardReq',forwardString);



socket.on('insertReceiverIdInMessageForwardRes', function (messages) {                        
var updatedMsg = messages.Messages;
       });
```

------------------Server Side code------------------

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('insertReceiverIdInMessageForwardReq', function (status) {

        io.emit('insertReceiverIdInMessageForwardRes', res);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // sending to individual socketid (private message)
   socket.to(<socketid>).emit('hey', 'I just met you');
// or you can do this as well
  io.sockets.connected[<socketid>].emit('hey', 'I just met you');
```

Please refer the documentation for more details: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/